# property setenabled keep false when I initialize this property of a textbox to false

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm new programming in javascript and I have this problem, in a web project I have two raddiobuttons(rbtn1 and rbtn2) and a textbox(txt1), when I select the rbtn1 his checked property is true (obviously) and the setenabled property of the txt1 must be true, and when I select the rbtn2 then the setenabked property of the txt1 must be false. I did it, and it works perfectly when I initialize the txt1's property, setenabled=true, but when I initialize this property to false it doesn't work.

Why happens this?, 
For extra information, I use devexpress controls in a asp.net and c# project.
Thanks for answer..

Hi, thank you for answer, and yes I´m using a C# asp.net project, but for this case I'm using javascript too. Here is the code of the radiobuttons

```
        <dx:ASPxRadioButton ID="rbtn" runat="server" Text="Disabled" 
                ClientIDMode="AutoID" ClientInstanceName="rbtn">
                <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="function(s, e) {
        disabled(s, e);}" />  </dx:ASPxRadioButton>

            <dx:ASPxRadioButton ID="rbtn1" runat="server" Text="Enabled" 
              ClientIDMode="AutoID" ClientInstanceName="rbtn1" Checked="True">  
<ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="function(s, e) {enabled(s, e);}" />
     </dx:ASPxRadioButton>
```

And here the javascript code

```
function disabled(s, e) {
        rbtn1.SetChecked(false);
        txt1.SetEnabled(false);
    }

    function enabled(s, e) {
        rbtn.SetChecked(false);
        txt1.SetEnabled(true);
    }
```

As I said it works perfectly only when I initialize the setenabled txt1's property to true

Comment: You can post part of your code. So that we can see where your problem is

Answer (score 0):

When ASP.NET renders controls, it turns them into a chunk of HTML. In this case you should check to see if the rendered controls keep the same ID (rbtn, rbtn1) etc.

Also, you need to check what they get rendered at as HTML controls. [Do a view->source in your browser after running] Typically they would be rendered inside an HTML  tag, so, if the tag is called form1, and the controls are rbtn and rbtn1, to enable/disable them you use:

document.form1.rbtn.disabled=true;
document.form1.rbtn1.disabled=false;

etc.

The API for the server-side controls that works for C# likely doesn't work for JS (unless DevExpress produce a JS library that mimics it that auto downloads at runtime, which I doubt)

Comment: Well, I did what you suggested and you were right, asp.net renders the control at as Html tag, but it still doesn't work with 'document.form1.rbtn.disabled' or ' document.getElementById('rb2')' or ' document.getElementById('<% rb2.clientId%>')'. 
I'm afraid you´re right devespress doesn't work well with JS

Comment: Take a look at the code-behind and see what ID the controls get rendered with. I'm sure it's something to do with the name property you set on the control....you can use that to do the setting of the enablement of the control.